# Mysql Time Difference calculation using Time Fields and a Trigger

Tags: mysql, time, triggers

So, I'm dealing with this MYSQL DB that has a table that stores posts with service start and end times.  The DATE is in a separate field.  Table looks like this:

[time entry table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOhZ.png)

I added the hrs field and what I want to do is setup a BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE EDIT trigger to populate the hrs field based on startTime and endTime entries as an INTEGER.

Start and End Time data IN THE DATABASE look like this:

08:00:00

Thanks for your help/advice!

Comment: Are you having any particular problem? BTW there is no BEFORE EDIT trigger option do you mean BEFORE UPDATE?

Comment: Sorry, yes - BEFORE UPDATE is what I meant.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that it's not calculating properly.  For example, if I have a start time of 08:00:00 and an end time of 09:15:00...it's calculating .25 instead of 1.25.  The BEFORE INSERT & UPDATE TRIGGER I'm using is:

SET NEW.hrs = MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(NEW.endTime,NEW.startTime)) / 60;